# Insert NVARCHAR string using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, datacontext

Here is the problem. I have a table in a SQL Server database

```
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    [userID]        INT             PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [userName]      NVARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
    [userEmail]     VARCHAR(127)    NOT NULL,
    [userComment]   NVARCHAR(2083)  NOT NULL,
    [userLanguage]  VARCHAR(63)     NOT NULL,
    [regTime]       DATE            NOT NULL,
    [hash]          VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
);
```

The specific part I have problems with is `NVARCHAR`.

I have the following C# code:

```
UsersDataContext context = new UsersDataContext();
User u = new User() {
    userName = name,
    userEmail = email,
    userComment = story,
    userLanguage = lang,
    hash = hash,
    regTime = System.DateTime.Now
};
context.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is that the row inserted into DB looks like this:

```
????    dbogatov@wpi.edu    ???
```

Russian (cyrillic) symbols are displaying as `???`.

Any ideas how to make `DataContext` insert proper `NVARCHAR`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make sure that `story` variable has the correct encoded values?

Comment: When you say " the row inserted into DB looks like this", what are you using to examine the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! Shame on me for such a stupid mistake.

I turns out that I did not update my .DBML file when I changed my db SCHEME to support NVARCHAR. So Entity Framework still treated my text as VARCHAR.

When I updated it, everything worked.

Comment: I changed all VARCHAR to NVARCHAR in stored procedures, tables and views, and (here is the trick!!!) updated my .DBML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding character encoding `"Charset=utf8"` in your database connection string. Should look like below:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Metadata;provider=Your Provide;provider connection string=&quot;server=ServerIP;User Id=UID;password=PASS;Persist Security Info=True;database=DB Name; Charset=utf8&quot;" providerName="Provider Name" /></connectionStrings>
```

Should work in your case.

Comment: Thank you!

I did what you said but server gives runtime error.

My new connection string looks like this

Data Source=SQL5007.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=***;User Id=***;Password=****;Charset=utf-8;

With different variations of the words "CharSet" and "UTF-8"

What I see is: Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. 

Are you sure you give me write parameter for MSSQL (not MySQL) string?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

check the Collation of the Database by setting it to the proper value
take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
i expect that this collation is what you need **Latin1_General_CI_AI**

Comment: I tried changing collation for some columns:

ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN userName
            nvarchar(128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL;

It does not work. Everything is still ??? even if I add new rows.

Thank you!

Comment: @Dima4kaBogatov try changing it for the entire database this happened to me once with Arabic Language